# JS input value assigning to variable - undefined

Tags: javascript, input

I'm really fresh to `JS`
Need some help because I don't understand a thing.
If I try to assign the whole line to variable, I can use this variable later, but the outcome of that is blank or undefined, when I'm trying to log this to console, or either alert that
using opera/chrome it's still the same, am I doing something wrong?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="username">
```

JS

not working

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

console.log(name);
```

can't do that either

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');

console.log(name.value);
```

innerHTML not working

---

I can do only that

```
console.log(document.getElementById('name').value);
```

---

---

**UPDATING THE CODE TO FULL EXAMPLE**
So I've changed the variable name to nameInp but it isn't working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="podaj imię">
    <input type="text" id="name2">
    <input type="text" id="name3">
    <!--
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="podaj hasło">
    <input type="password" id="confPassword" placeholder="powtórz hasło">
    -->
    <button id="submit" onclick="check();" value="wyślij">wyślij</button>

    <!--
    <p id="para"></p>
    -->   

    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="center2"></div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


var nameInp = document.getElementById('name').value;
var btn = document.getElementById('submit');


function check(){
    console.log(nameInp);
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. When gets the JavaScript executed? It seems like it gets executed before the DOM has finished with loading. So you try to retrieve your element before it's even there.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `name` is a bad name for an identifier, rename the element. Most likely you'll get blank from `value` because there's no value at the time your code is running, `innerHTML` is not a property of `input` element, hence that returns you `undefined`.

Comment: @Teemu  
i know that innerHTML works only after period, dot and it can take value as blank

Comment: @CodeF0x
do i have to use window.onload function?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/1848654 for why using the the same name for the HTML `id` attribute and a global JavaScript variable is a bad idea.

Comment: @melpomene
thank You :)

Comment: @wilk85 Nope, `input` is an empty element, and it can't have HTML. If you set its `innerHTML`, it is just a custom attribute to the said element, and has no reflection to attributes of an input or layout of a page.

Comment: @Teemu
thank You, my mistake, i should use then document.write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code reduced to the relevant parts:

```js
var nameInp = document.getElementById('name').value;

function check() {
    console.log(nameInp);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="podaj imię">

<button id="submit" onclick="check();" value="wyślij">wyślij</button>
```

The problem is that `var nameInp = document.getElementById('name').value;` is executed right when `main.js` is loaded (which happens as part of the whole page loading). At that point the input field has no value yet, so this is equivalent to `var nameInp = "";`.

Later, when the user clicks on the submit button, the `check` function runs, but nothing has changed the `nameInp` variable. It still contains `""`, so you get no output.

Here's a clearer demonstration of the problem, where the initial value is not `""` but `"initial value"`:

```js
var nameInp = document.getElementById('name').value;

function check() {
    console.log(nameInp);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="podaj imię" value="initial value">

<button id="submit" onclick="check();" value="wyślij">wyślij</button>
```

Every time you click on `wyślij`, `initial value` is printed because that's what `nameInp` was initially set to.

Fix:

```js
var nameInp = document.getElementById('name');

function check() {
    console.log(nameInp.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="podaj imię">

<button id="submit" onclick="check();" value="wyślij">wyślij</button>
```

Here we only retrieve the `.value` of the input field at the time `check()` is run, i.e. when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank You, that finally worked good, all time i was doing
    console.log(name).value;
so i guess i'm still fresh :) 
I gave +1 and the correct answer :) 
thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can't see anything in the console because you're outputting the value of the input when the script is called so essentially on page load. At this point the input box hasn't been filled yet. That's the `console.log` doesn't show anything.

You can, for example, run your function every time the user types inside the input box. For this you will need an event listener:

Select the element you desire to 'watch' and call the [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method on it. It takes the event type and a callback function as parameters.

Lastly, in the callback function, we get the value of the input box by accessing the target of the event: `e.target`. `e` being the event object and `e.target` the property `target` of the event.

The code below will call a `console.log()` every time the user types in the input box:

```js
document.querySelector('#username').addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);    
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username">
```

Comment: that is a nice example thank You, but i just wanted to be simple, without eventListener

Answer (score -1):

I have made a script for all three cases, use it according to your need.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        function Consolify() {
            var firstMethod = document.getElementById('name').value;
            console.log('firstMethod = ', firstMethod);
            var secondMethod = document.getElementById('name');
            console.log('secondMethod = ', secondMethod.value);
            console.log('thirdMethod = ', document.getElementById('name').value);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="username">
    <button onclick="Consolify()">Consolify</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Run this code in a browser and look for console, it is well tested